# 'ENVFILE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, knex.js

[ENVFILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZL0D.png)

When I run the migrations. I see this issue. Basically, I'm trying to implement the create_photos_table.

1. Cloned repo
2. Ran `cp .env.example .env.jest` and `yarn test --passWithNoTests`
3. Changed the password in .env.jest

Comment: Looks like the `ENVFILE=...` line, should have been part of the previous command - not a new command by itself. Try running `yarn db:migration create_photos_table ENVFILE=.env knex migrate:make create_photos_table` as one command

Comment: Tried running mentioned command but No Luck!

Comment: Then we'll need some more information. The error you report, is because you've attempted to run the `ENVFILE=..` line as a separate command, but there' is no command called `ENVFILE`. If you've tried my suggestion, but it still fails, then please update the question with any new errors.

Comment: Linux or Windows OS?

Comment: I got this on Windows OS

Answer (score 4):

from the documentation of [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) which is what Knex is probably using here:

```
$ ENVFILE=.env.staging react-native run-ios           # bash
$ SET ENVFILE=.env.staging && react-native run-ios    # windows
$ env:ENVFILE=".env.staging"; react-native run-ios    # powershell
```

So in your case, you will need to use `SET ENVFILE=.env` on Windows instead of `ENVFILE=.env`.